# restore Computer Modern font for mathversion{normal} when using wrisym

Tags: fonts

I have added

```
\usepackage[uprightmonomath]{wrisym}
```

to the preamble to get Mathematica input fonts.  I can access them by using `\mathversion{mono}` and `\mathversion{monobold}`.

But `wrisym` has also changed the fonts for `mathversion{normal}` and `\mathversion{bold}` to Times.  What can I do to make the `normal` and `bold` correspond to the default Computer Modern?

(p.s. The default main-body text font also changed to Times.  So I also needed to get the default main-body text to be Computer Modern.  With help from [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg), I achieved it by adding `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{cmr}` to the preamble.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you don't want to load `wrisym`, but rather just to define new math versions:

```
\DeclareMathVersion{mono}
\DeclareMathVersion{monobold}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{mono}{OML}{wttum}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{mono}{OT1}{wttr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{mono}{OMS}{wtty}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{mono}{OMX}{wttv}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{monobold}{OML}{wttum}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{monobold}{OT1}{wttr}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{monobold}{OMS}{wtty}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{monobold}{OMX}{wttv}{b}{n}
```

This code in your document will define the math fonts to use under

```
\mathversion{mono}
```

or

```
\mathversion{monobold}
```

without doing any change to the default text and math fonts.

Comment: This is very nice; and things are really shaping up.  I still need to address two things (but I got one of them on my own; woot!).  (1) By adding these definitions, the monospaced fonts became narrower than before.  But after reading in the manual msymdoc.pdf, I noticed that I could fix this by changing `tt` to `cr`; *e.g.* change `wttum` to `wcrum`.. *etc.*  (2) There are a handful special *Mathematica* characters (like double-struck letters and "Alias-Delimiter") which I need to access.  Would you help me find how to get these characters?

Comment: @QuantumDot Look in `wrisym.sty` under "Delimiters" and "Double Struck". My impression is that you're asking for a whole new package.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm doing now: and I found that I can get the necessary characters by adding *e.g.* `\DeclareMathSymbol{\DoubleStruckG}{\mathord}{symbols}{number}
\let\dsg=\DoubleStruckG` to the preamble.  Where I need to figure out what `number` I need.

Comment: @QuantumDot You get those only if the `symbols` font is one of the Mathematica fonts. It's far more complicated than just adding `\DeclareMathSymbols`.

Comment: Are you serious??  That's really depressing.  I just need like 4 double-struck characters, and the alias delimiter...  Ok, I'll spend another half-hour before giving up.

Comment: Actually, I think I can get it... the numbers are really screwy, but since I just need a handful of them, I can play around and I think I'll be able to get it!  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @QuantumDot -- since the number of doublestruck letters you need is limited, this question might help: [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)